# MXMLC in Flex SDK 4.5 doesn't work on Mac OS 10.8

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, osx-mountain-lion, flex4.5, mxmlc

Starting mxmlc on the latest mac exits with error message:

Error: This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM.
Please install the desired version.

How to fix?

Answer (score 41):

The latest java update for mac removed the 32bit mode and thus doesn't offer the -d32.
There are various solutions for this problem:

- #### Remove the -d32 part of the mxmlc script.

  The mxmlc file is a "regular text file" that can be edited with any editor. vim should do the job. The easy fix is to just "comment" the "-d32" part out like this:

  ```
  # if [ "$isOSX" != "" -a "$HOSTTYPE" = "x86_64" -a "$check64" != "" ]; then
  #      D32='-d32'
  # fi
  ```
- #### Use new Flex SDK

  The problem seems to be gone with the Flex 4.8 SDK
- #### Change to old java version

  1.) Remove the old java http://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml
   2.) Install the older version by typing "java --version" in the command line

Comment: you can also do this same edit in the "compc" script, which is in the same directory as the mxmlc script (`${flex.sdk}/bin/compc`). a little context can be found here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fd9.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf5fb32-7ff5

Comment: The new flex fixed this issue for me. Thank you